# How can I get tables name from sys.tables and store the output in a variable?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure where a table name and database name collect 
using cursor from different two tables.
But my problem is when I run a query to find out a table exists in a database or not, then show a error.
Now how can I run the query and store output into a variable?

```
Declare @table_exist nvarchar(200),@val1 nvarchar(200),@return1 nvarchar(200);
  SET @table_exist= 
    'SELECT 1 FROM '+@db_name+'.sys.tables 
    where name='+@table_name+'';
  EXEC sp_executesql @table_exist,@return1 OUTPUT;  
  select @return1;
```

ERROR:

```
Invalid column name 'table name'
```

Comment: It seems like very dirty written code.

Comment: then please improve it (as I have already done) or write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [quotename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) when building dynamic query:

```
   SET @table_exist= 
     'SELECT 1 FROM '+ quotename(@db_name)+'.sys.tables 
     where name='+quotename(@table_name)+'';
```

When facing such an error the best would be to `print @table_exists` and see what is actually built.

**I haven't looked properly at your query. You are missing apostrophes:**

```
   SET @table_exist= 
     'SELECT 1 FROM '+ quotename(@db_name)+'.sys.tables 
     where name=''' + @table_name +'''';
```

**UPDATE:**

When using output variable you should set it in a query:

```
  SET @table_exist= 
    'SELECT @return1 = 1 FROM ' + quotename(@db_name) + '.sys.tables 
    where name='''+@table_name+'''';
```

To prevent result set from returning to client, create temporary table and insert result set into it. In this case this will leave only one result set, the result of `select @return1`:

```
  declare @tbl table (exist bit)
  insert into @tbl
  EXEC sp_executesql @table_exist, N'@return1 nvarchar(200) out', @return1 OUT;
  select @return1;
```

Comment: When i print the @table_exist then shows: SELECT 1 FROM [db_name].sys.tables where name=[table name]. For that reason i get the same error again. --Invalid column name 'Table name'.pls help

Comment: thanks, its works. But this line  EXEC sp_executesql @table_exist,@return1 OUTPUT  produce huge message and showing error "The query has exceeded the maximum number of result sets that can be displayed in the results grid". How can i prevent to show the message.Please help.

Comment: @riad please check my revised answer.

Comment: @riad Are you calling this code in a loop? Could you post complete code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11829/discussion-between-riad-and-nikola-markovinovic)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot do chat ATM. Please bear in mind that each `select` you do produces result set. If this does not help you resolve your issue, please post new question explaining what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to write your query by using `'`  and `"` properly . Which makes less mistakes while writing query.

The error on you code is that you are confused by using only `'`. Best to use `'` for variable only.

Write your code as:

```
"SELECT 1 FROM  ' "+@db_name+" '.sys.tables 
    where name=' "+@table_name+" ' ";
```