# How to get table names from sys.tables in java?

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

We need to get tables names instead of referenced_object_id from SQL server 2005 in Eclipse. Its done like that,but not getting tables names:

```
   Statement smt = con.createStatement();
            smt.executeQuery("SELECT * from table_references");
            ResultSet rs = smt.getResultSet();

            while (rs.next()) { 
                String column1 = rs.getString("referenced_object_id");
                String column2 = rs.getString("name");
                String column3 = rs.getString("parent_column_id");
                String column4 = rs.getString("referenced_column_id");

                String sql = "SELECT name from sys.tables WHERE object_id='" + column1 + "'";

                System.out.println(column1 + " | " + column2 + " | " + column3 + " | " + column4);
```

Comment: What's your question or problem?  In your snippet you're not querying the database, just creating a query string in `sql`

Comment: which stament do you want to execute? could you please make your question less confusing. You can look some sql examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784861/how-can-i-get-tables-name-from-sys-tables-and-store-the-output-in-a-variable

Comment: Fixed question a bit.

Comment: You have to make a join between the `table_references` and `sys.tables`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the metadata from the database in order to get the names of the tables.

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();  
ResultSet rs = meta.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

Have a look over here -  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29 - it will help you.

Comment: `Collection classes = owlModel.getUserDefinedOWLNamedClasses();
   for (Iterator it = classes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
       OWLNamedClass cls = (OWLNamedClass) it.next();
       cls.getName();
       
    smt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Country");
    ResultSet rs2 = smt.getResultSet();
    while (rs2.next()) { 
     String col = rs.getString("countryName");
     cls.createOWLIndividual(col);
    }
   `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set is closed. Im getting error here too

Comment: The problem comes from the way you are using the resulset. According to the javadoc of `getResultset`
_Retrieves the current result as a ResultSet object. This method should be called only once per result._ . So, instead of doing this:
    `smt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Country"); 
    ResultSet rs2 = smt.getResultSet();` 
Use this one:
    `ResultSet rs2 = smt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Country");`